# FB page postings from my android app can't be seen by other users

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-android-sdk

I made an application on android to post in my Fb page and it's also working. But the problem is other users can't see those posts in my page. Only the admin can see it. I also made the page and posts as public and provide visibility settings Also provide page_access token with manage_pages and public_stream permissions.

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("message","message");              
postParams.putString("name","name");
postParams.putString("link",link);
postParams.putString("picture",picture);
postParams.putString("access_token", pageaccessToken);

Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

public void onCompleted(Response response) {
    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                                                    if (error != null) {
    Log.e("FACEBOOK ERROR", ""+ error.getErrorMessage());
            } else {
                                                        JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                                                .getGraphObject()
                                                                .getInnerJSONObject();
                                                        String postId = null;
                                                        try {
                                                            postId = graphResponse
                                                                    .getString("id");
                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                        }
                                                }
}
};

Request request = new Request(null,pageid+"/feed",postParams, HttpMethod.POST,callback);
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

I am also trying to do it with fb api explorer.
[image]

But here also it provide the same result. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Please check that the **sandbox mode** is disabled in the App Settings for your application.